# Swift NSDocument subclass of readFromURL:ofType:error: not accepted?

Tags: swift, nsdocument

I'm not understanding an NSDocument requirement; I just need to record the url so that on a later restore of windows, the url will be retrieved again. But I'm using Swift:  I had added the "@objc" routine thinking it was different.   I'm coming from my objective-c heritage and it appears the stack names use that heritage.  The latest Swift version (xcode 8.3) is even more different than the 7.3.1 vintage!

What I'm trying to do is associate a document with a url, and when asked dump it to disk. The doc will become a plist once I sort this out. From my original question the 1st function I can ditch?

```
class PlayItem : NSObject {
    var name : String = k.item
    var link : URL = URL.init(string: "http://")!
    var time : TimeInterval
    var rank : Int

    override init() {
        name = k.item
        link = URL.init(string: "http://")!
        time = 0.0
        rank = 0
        super.init()
    }
    init(name:String, link:URL, time:TimeInterval, rank:Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.link = link
        self.time = time
        self.rank = rank
        super.init()
    }
    override var description : String {
        return String(format: "%@: %p '%@'", self.className, self, name)
    }
}

class Document : NSDocument {

    @objc func readFromURL(url: NSURL, ofType typeName: String, error outError: NSErrorPointer) -> Bool {
        self.fileURL = url as URL
        self.fileType = typeName
        return true
    }

    convenience init(contentsOf: URL, ofType: String) throws {
        self.init()

        switch ofType {
            case "internal":
            self.fileURL = contentsOf
            self.fileType = ofType
            break

        default:
            Swift.print("nyi")
        }
        throw NSError(domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain, code: unimpErr, userInfo: nil)
   }

    override func read(from url: URL, ofType typeName: String) throws {
        switch typeName {
        case "internal":
            self.fileURL = url
            self.fileType = typeName
            break

        case "h2o":
            let data = try Data.init(contentsOf: url)
            do {
                try! self.read(from: data, ofType: typeName)
                self.fileURL = url as URL
                self.fileType = typeName
            }
            break

        default:
            Swift.print("nyi \(typeName)")
            break
    }
    throw NSError(domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain, code: unimpErr, userInfo: nil)

    override func write(to url: URL, ofType typeName: String) throws {
        switch typeName {
        case "DocumentType":
            var temp = [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]()
            for key in playlists.keys {
                var list = Array<AnyObject>()
                for playitem in playlists[key] as! [PlayItem] {
                    let item : [String:AnyObject] = [k.name:playitem.name as AnyObject, k.link:playitem.link.absoluteString as AnyObject, k.time:playitem.time as AnyObject, k.rank:playitem.rank as AnyObject]
                    list.append(item as AnyObject)
                }
                temp.append([k.name:key as AnyObject, k.list:list as AnyObject])
            }
            UserDefaults.standard.set(temp, forKey: UserSettings.Playlists.keyPath)
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            break

        case "h2o":
            let dict = NSDictionary.init()
            dict.setValue(playlists, forKey: UserSettings.Playlists.keyPath)
            dict.setValue(settings, forKey: UserSettings.PlayPrefs.keyPath)
            dict.write(to: url, atomically: true)
            break

        default:
            Swift.print("nyi \(typeName)")
            throw NSError(domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain, code: unimpErr, userInfo: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Getting this error:

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff89ed52cb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff9ece048d objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff89f53c3d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   AppKit                              0x00007fff87e65a45 -[NSDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:] + 419
4   AppKit                              0x00007fff87b66dd7 -[NSDocument _initWithContentsOfURL:ofType:error:] + 172
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff87b66cbc -[NSDocument initWithContentsOfURL:ofType:error:] + 231
```

Which I suspect the throws are active but my breaks at each function is never hit?  I suppose my recent menu will never be proper until this is resolved, and each run creates more windows than last, so I'm hoping resolution will remedy these all.

Comment: According to the documentation the Swift translation is `func read(from url: URL, ofType typeName: String) throws`.

Comment: What do you do to create the document?

Comment: Haven't gotten to creating or testing writing; so far I create manually via plist editor for "h2o" files,  while "DocumentType" being no url is written to defaults.  But I'm stuck as I cannot break in any routine to triage what looks like a throw firing?

Comment: I'm sorry, my question wasn't clear. How do you create a new document object? Or which action triggers the creation of a new document object?

Comment: I literally have not created a doc yet; I just edit one up in the plist editor and double cllick it, which launches an init(url) method. But I have a func to create but not wired up yet; I'll update my question to show it - but writing is a ways off - I will support 2 doc types, where contents are in a plist (defaults) and contents in plist (save to a file url).

Comment: Are both document types the same class? Maybe a `NSDocument` is created instead of a `Document`.

Comment: Thanks, but I only have the one document class.  I think I'm past the error with this code; I had a snippet that was explicitly creating a document of my class for my 1st window controller that for some reason had a nil document. I suspect my Info.plist had a problem.